# Why aren't my jQuery/css animations showing on iphone when called from a .submit() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iphone, performance

My problem is I want to have a div fade in when a form is submitted. If I simply use:

```
jQuery('form.uc-cart-checkout-form').submit(function() {
    jQuery("#processing-screen").fadeIn();
});
```

This works properly on my desktop but doesn't on my iphone. On the iPhone it seems once the browser begins loading a new page, it stops processing any remaining javascript within the .submit() function. As a result the browser never runs the .fadeIn() function.

I was able to sort of get around this by delaying the form submit, such as:

```
jQuery('form.uc-cart-checkout-form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 1000); // delay submitting form 1 second

    jQuery("#processing-screen").fadeIn();
});
```

But this causes errors in some of my more complex form's submission data. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light as to what is going on and perhaps how to achieve this?
Cheers

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome and safari on iphone. Same behavior on both.